# Connecting Bing Ads API using node-soap

Tags: node.js, soap, bing, node-soap, bing-ads-api

I am trying to connect to bing ads soap api using node-soap. I have created the request as suggested in bing [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bing-ads-reporting-submitgeneratereport.aspx#SubmitGenerateReportRequest%20Message). But each time I try to connect the response states the Invalid credentials (Error code - 105) Message - Authentication failed. Either supplied credentials are invalid or the account is inactive.

I was able to authenticate the API using sample C# code provided by bing. So, its clear that the credentials/token are working perfectly fine.

Is there a way to identify the issue with my approach or in my node code.

```
soap.createClient(url, function (err, client) {
    if (err) {
        console.log("err", err);
    } else {
        client.addSoapHeader({
            'AuthenticationToken': '<AuthenticationToken>',
            'DeveloperToken': '<DeveloperToken>',
            'CustomerId': '<CustomerId>',
            'CustomerAccountId': '<CustomerAccountId>',
        });        
        client.SubmitGenerateReport(args, function (err, result) {
            if (err) {
                console.log("err", err.body);
            } else {
                console.log(result);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

PS: Bing Documentation Sucks. Hail Stackoverflow!

Comment: Did you got it working and do you mind sharing how? thanks

Comment: Did you, or did @Christoph get it working, and do you mind sharing now?

Comment: @amit, unfortunately I did not. I am working with other tools now to access the api since I primarily needed it for analysis.

Comment: @Christoph, Sorry for the delayed response. 
Yup, I got it working. When I compared my request xml with the request xml generated with WcfTestClient, I found my request wasn't properly formatted. On fixing that I was able to call the API. I hope that helps :)

Comment: Thanks, I managed to get it working with the answer posted to this question.

Comment: @Dpk can you share your full code if possible. how you generate AuthenticationToken, is there any node js way to generate ?

Answer (score 5):

You need to prefix each key in your headers with `tns`, e.g: `tns:AuthenticationToken`